# Clustering based on correlation

Tags: cluster-analysis, correlation

I have a pearson correlation matrix with how different foods are correlated with each other.

I would like to create groups of foods that can be analyzed together, therefore I would like to categorize them into clusters.

I want to cluster these foods into categories using the following criteria:

1) I would like to maximize the correlation within each of the clusters
2) I would like to setup a minimum correlation for each group (i.e. each cluster needs to have a correlation of >0.7).

Is there a machine learning algorithm that would be applicable for this case.

Answer (score 1):

Use hierarchical clustering with

1. Complete linkage
2. Cut at height 0.7
3. Transform similaritires into distances